# Is there efficiency lost when declaring an automatic variable in a frequently opening block scope { }?

Tags: c, scope, compiler-optimization, lifetime

In K&R it is stated:

> An automatic variable declared and initialized in a block is
>   initialized each time the block is entered.

Here is a code snippet solely for communicating the question.  Two options are shown; declaring error_string in the main function body and declaring it within the block scope of an if().

The question is, if the option2 declaration is used, can the compiler be relied upon to optimize the act of repeatedly instantiating the string?

It may make the code more readable to declare variables closest to where they are used. Limiting their scope as much as possible is perhaps a good design practice.  Could doing so have any appreciable detriment to efficiency?

```
#define MAX_ERROR_STRING_LEN 1024

void process_results(int *results, int n_results)
{
    int i;
    char error_string[MAX_ERROR_STRING_LEN]; //option1

    for (i = 0; i < n_results; i++) //suppose n_results == 1 million, 98% "FAILURE"
    {
        if (results[i] == FAILURE)
        {
            char error_string[MAX_ERROR_STRING_LEN];//option2

            get_error_string(error_string, MAX_ERROR_STRING_LEN - 1);

            fprintf(debug_log, "Error: %s\n", error_string);
        }
    }
}
```

on a related note, should this be avoided:

```
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(error_string); i++)
        printf("%c", error_string[i]);
```

in favor of:

```
    int len = strlen(error_string);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        printf("%c", error_string[i]);
```

or will that be optimized despite dependence on run-time data?

Edit - no changes just adding research:

I *think* this confirms the block scoped variables are repeatedly created and destroyed (for all intents and purposes to the programmer):

> A.4.1 Storage Class There are two storage classes: automatic and
>   static. Several keywords, together with the context of an object's
>   declaration, specify its storage class. **Automatic objects are local to
>   a block (Par.9.3), and are discarded on exit from the block.**

Most of the rest seems to refer to lexical scope rather than linkage:

> A.11.1 Lexical Scope ... The scope of a parameter of a function
>   definition begins at the start of the block defining the function, and
>   persists through the function; the scope of a parameter in a function
>   declaration ends at the end of the declarator. The scope of an
>   identifier declared at the head of a block begins at the end of its
>   declarator, and persists to the end of the block.

Regarding Lexical scope?:

> The scope of a name is the part of the program within which the name
>   can be used. For an automatic variable declared at the beginning of a
>   function, the scope is the function in which the name is declared.
>   Local variables of the same name in different functions are unrelated.
>   The same is true of the parameters of the function, which are in
>   effect local variables.

also

> A name also has a scope, which is the region of the program in which
>   it is known, and a linkage, which determines whether the same name in
>   another scope refers to the same object or function. Scope and linkage
>   are discussed in Par.A.11.

Comment: The common compilers will probably allocate it only once anyway in the same stack frame as other function variables. This is not guaranteed, but again. it's a common way they do it.

Comment: Your `error_string` is not initialized in either case.

Comment: Even if the buffer were initialised; the  function call and the printf() are way more expensive.

Comment: Regarding: `for (i = 0; i < strlen(error_string); i++)`  This would be much better written as `for (i = 0; error_string[i]; i++)`  Which avoids the call(s) to `strlen()`, making the overall loop much faster.  An even better way. which limits the scope of the variable 'i' would be: `for ( size_t i = 0; error_string[i]; i++)`

Comment: @pmg true it isn't initialized, but to wit, it is allocated.  wildplasser - note the disclaimer this code snippet is not being optimized, it's meant to be a simple illustration for communicating the concept.  user3629249 what you've said is true.

Comment: in your example the variable is allocated on the stack which means that it doesn't have any effect on performance. allocating or deallocating a stack frame is as simple as moving the stack pointer back or forward by an amount known at compile time (ie. the total size of the local variables). so the only additional cost in this case could potentially be from any 
unnecessary initialization that occurs each time.

Comment: @ChrisRollins Ahhhh.  That makes sense, but what makes heap allocation expensive?  Thanks

Comment: It can be but not always. Two reasons come to mind. 1) When memory is allocated to the heap, the lifetime is arbitrary. Objects being freed in arbitrary order leaves holes. The memory allocator needs a strategy to keep track of these holes so that the memory can be used again.
2) The heap tends to be less favorable for CPU caching since the objects can be in arbitrary locations on the heap.
It's more that the stack is reliably fast but the heap can get slow when used heavily in a disorganized way since that then causes the memory allocator and CPU to work in unfavorable conditions.

Answer (score 4):

The local variable `error_string` is not initialized, there is no overhead in declaring it with block scope instead of function scope. Some compilers might allocate temporary stack space for `error_string` upon entering the block scope and deallocate it upon leaving this scope, which involves a single instruction in both cases, but most compilers will allocate space for all local variables in a single step at the beginning of the function.

Since you are concerned with efficiency, note that both code fragments posted to print a string are very inefficient compared to this:

```
    fputs(error_string, stdout);
```

Comment: With modern optimizing compilers the 'allocate stack' is often moot. Quite often, the stack is not allocated, it's just various variable access is translated into various offset from the SP which is never modified, unless another function is called.